# Does a UHF/VHF handheld transceiver kit exist?

Tags: vhf, uhf, ht, transceiver

I am a licensed ham looking for a UHF/VHF handheld transceiver kit. Unfortunately so far I was only able to find broken links, i.e. Ten-Tec used to produce exactly such a thing but they just don't anymore. I'm looking for a kit, not a finished product. My search has not been successful so far.

Are there **any** such kits in current production?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98086/discussion-on-question-by-mike-looking-for-uhf-vhf-kit).

Comment: Why is this on hold? There obviously are not many kits to begin with. The goal is to get a list of all that are available. So this is not opinion based. We are talking about kits, not about commercial radios.

Comment: This is not opinion based!!!

Comment: The original close reason really should have been "product recommendations", not "opinion-based" — but we have generally allowed questions that are about "does something in this category exist at all" (usually for software), so I've edited the question to be more clearly that and reopened it.

Comment: Thank you very much! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://fofio.blogspot.com/2015/07/radio-kit-guide.html) site lists several kits and is the most current and complete list I could find (list is reproduced here).

Disclaimer: operation of devices linked depends on your jurisdiction. In any case you need the proper license to operate these devices.

- http://stores.ebay.com/24hrsradioshop
- http://ae9rb.com/
- http://www.ebay.com/usr/ag6bd
- http://amateurradiokits.in/
- http://www.amateurradioreceivers.net/index.htm
- https://bit.ly/2OYINVm
- http://breadboardradio.com/
- http://www.crkits.com/
- http://www.cumbriadesigns.co.uk/kits.htm
- http://cycle24kits.com/
- http://www.danssmallpartsandkits.net/
- http://www.dzkit.com/
- https://www.qrphamradiokits.com/
- http://emtech.steadynet.com/
- http://www.etherkit.com/
- http://www.4sqrp.com/kitIndex.php
- http://products.foxdelta.com/
- http://www.genesisradio.com.au/order.html
- http://www.gqrp.com/sudden.htm
- http://www.hamgadgets.com/
- http://www.hamtronics.com/menu_products.htm
- http://www.hanssummers.com/
- https://www.qrp-labs.com/
- http://heathkit.com/
- https://hfprojects2.com/
- http://hfsignals.com/
- http://www.hobbypcb.com/amateur-radio
- http://wb9kzy.com/ham.htm
- http://www.jumaradio.com/juma/
- https://kc9on.com/shop/
- http://www.qsl.net/k5bcq/Kits/Kits.html
- http://www.kanga-products.co.uk/
- http://www.kitradio.co.uk/
- http://www.kitsandparts.com/index.php

Comment: Please restate the list in your answer, so that it is still useful if the linked site goes away.

Comment: Also, OP asked specifically about VHF/UHF kits, most of the links I looked at only had HF kits if any RF kits at all.

Comment: Well, please read the comment above. He wanted the list to be reprinted here. You are right most kits are HF, but there are a few FM Kits. I should also say that I am the OP